# With Oracle XML Tables do XQuery selects use XmlIndexes?

Tags: oracle, xquery, xmltype, xmltable, xmlindex

I am trying to retrieve keys and parent keys from some structured xml stored as binary xml in oracle. I have tried created unstructured index and also an index with a structured component. The structured component works fine when doing a SELECT against XMLTABLE() but I cannot retrieve values of parent node using XMLTable. I am therefore trying the following Xquery to retrieve parent values but this is not using the index at all. Does this style of query support using XmlIndexes? I can't find anything in the docs that say either way.

```
SELECT y.*
FROM xml_data x, XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces( DEFAULT 'namespace'),
'for $i in /foo/bar
   return element r {
      $i/someKey
     ,element parentKey { $i/../someKey }   
 }'
PASSING x.import_xml
COLUMNS
   someKey VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'someKey'
  ,parentKey VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'parentKey'
) y
```

Thanks, Tom